# binary activation function for autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have an autoencoder that has two output( decoded,pred_w), one output is the reconstructed input image and other one is a reconstructed binary image. I used sigmoid activation function in the last layer but the outputs are float number and I need the network label each pixel as 0 or 1. I attached my code here. could you please guide me what should I do to solve this problem? 
thanks.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise,Dropout
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import keract
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda;

#-----------------building w train---------------------------------------------
w_main = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4,1))
w_main=w_main.astype(np.float32)
w_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28,1),dtype='float32')
w_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_main
w_expand.reshape(1,28,28,1)
w_expand=np.repeat(w_expand,49999,0)

#-----------------building w validation---------------------------------------------
w_valid = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4,1))
w_valid=w_valid.astype(np.float32)
wv_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28,1),dtype='float32')
wv_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_valid
wv_expand.reshape(1,28,28,1)
wv_expand=np.repeat(wv_expand,9999,0)

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4,1))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28,1),dtype='float32')
wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
wt_expand.reshape(1,28,28,1)
#wt_expand=np.repeat(wt_expand,10000,0)

#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
DrO1=Dropout(0.25)(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',name='reconstructed_I')(DrO1)


#-----------------------adding w---------------------------------------
#add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + Kr.backend.constant(w_expand))
#encoded_merged=Kr.layers.Add()([encoded,wtm])

add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + wtm)
encoded_merged = add_const(encoded)
encoder=Model(inputs=image, outputs= encoded_merged)
encoder.summary()

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#encoded_merged = Input((28, 28, 2))
deconv1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
DrO2=Dropout(0.25)(deconv3)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(DrO2) 

#decoder=Model(inputs=encoded_merged, outputs=decoded)
#decoder.summary()
model=Model(inputs=image,outputs=decoded)
#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w')(decoded)
convw2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w')(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w')(convw2)
DrO3=Dropout(0.25)(convw3)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W')(DrO3)  
# reconsider activation (is W positive?)
# should be filter=1 to match W
w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])


#----------------------training the model--------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------Data preparesion----------------------------------------

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
# is accuracy sensible metric for this model?
w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss={'decoder_output':'mse','reconstructed_W':'mse'}, metrics=['mae'])
w_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=128, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='E:/tmp/AutewithW200', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False)])
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this inside the model, you can use `K.round()` from `keras.backend`. Notice this will not be differentiable and will not be able to be used very well in training.

If you need just the results, you can simple define a threshold (usually 0.5) and:

```
binary_reslts = results > threshold
```

### Add metrics to your model

You can see the results by adding metrics that round the data.
Standard metrics for this could be `"accuracy"` or `"categorical_accuracy"`. You you can define your own metrics like:

```
def diceMetric(yTrue, yPred):
    yTrue = K.batch_flatten(yTrue)
    yPred = K.batch_flatten(yPred)

    #round
    yPred = K.greater(yPred, 0.5)
    yPred = K.cast(yPred, K.floatx())

    intersection = yPred * yTrue
    sum = yTrue + yPred

    return (2*intersection + K.epsilon())/(sum + K.epsilon())
```

Metrics are added in `compile`:

```
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=..., metrics = [diceMetric, 'categorical_accuracy'])
```

Metrics do not affect training, they're just feedback for you to know what's happening.

Comment: Thank you. but I have a binary image in output that I like the network label each pixel of it like 0 or 1 and I do not know I should put a threshold after learning? I want to see the effect during learning.

Comment: Thank you, but where should I use these metrics? do they use in learning and affect on learning or not? I should put them on the output of the last layer?

Comment: Thank you. now, you have two metrics diceMetric and categorical _accuracy, right? if I want more metrics, I should define a function for them and put them in a list as you did?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need your network to output exactly 0 or 1? You can interpret the output of your network as probability measure, of how likely it is that an input pixel correponds to class 0 or 1.
So during training the model tries to approximate the unknown probability distribution.

When it comes to predictions, you can use a threshold like .5 or you could use something like otsu threshold. Then you will obtain an binary output. Unfortunately thresholds will create some gaps or shrink the area of some predicted shapes.

Note:
typically you want to down and upsample in an autoencoder, because otherwise the model,could learn that the idendity function is optimal.

Comment: for output layer, it is better to have a sigmoid activation with kernel size (1,1)  to have an output as I mentioned or each activation and kernel size can be used?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. You could try softmax activation which enables you to train more than two classes. At the end you just have to get an output that fits the shape of your training label.

Comment: I want to produce a binary image in the output and I like to minimize the difference between the input image and it.

Comment: I have two input in this autoencoder one of them is a gray image and other is a binary image. the last layer in my structure tries to compare the output of sigmoid with this binary image, so I think it should have 0 or 1 values instead of values between 0, 1. due to this, I do not know what should I do that loss function compute a true value? I should use a threshold during learning? I am really confused. could you please help me with this issue.

Comment: What do you mean with input? You got two images running through your network? Or you got one, running through your network and the other one is your label?! Please do some research on binary cross-entropy. And no, you should not use a threshold during learning, this is just for predictions after learning phase.